# Can we create textbox right next to selectonemenu component when we fire selectoneMenu valueChangeListener event

Tags: jsf

want to create textbox on the fly is it possible?
Select Report to run:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{reportBean.selectReport}">
    <f:selectItems value = "#{reportBean.allReports}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{reportBean.getReqID}" render="reqID"> </f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you be more specific in what you don't understand? Answering those questions will improve your chances of getting a good response here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: every time create new textbox?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to show/hide the `<h:inputText>` based on the selected value on your `<h:selectOneMenu>`. Yes, this can be easily achieved with plain JSF.

Note that if you use set the `rendered` attribute as `false` the component won't appear in the component tree, so there will be no way it can't be referenced for any call (not even ajax calls). In order to *update* it, you should wrap the component inside another component like `<h:panelGroup>` and render the wrapper. Basic example:

```
<h:form id="frmRep">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{reportBean.selectReport}">
        <f:selectItems value = "#{reportBean.allReports}" />
        <!--
          assuming your reportBean.getReqID method will change the value of
          reportBean.showReqID attribute to render/not render it and works well
        -->
        <f:ajax listener="#{reportBean.getReqID}" render="pnlRepName" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:panelGroup id="pnlRepName">
        <h:inputText id="reqID" rendered="#{reportBean.showReqID}"
            value="#{reportBean.reportName}" />
    <h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

For this specific requirement instead, I won't recommend using an ajax call since it has to go to the server to only check if the component should or should not be showed to the user. I would opt for a JavaScript solution to handle this just on client side.